# Flash Memory Test for Radiation Hardness Assurance

Tags: linux, memory, arm

I want to do a long-term radiation memory test on an ARM-based Linux distribution (Linux 4.4.12 on a CORE9G25 Device with 256 kB NAND Flash Memory). To be precise, I would like to define a certain memory area of the flash memory, write data onto it, wait for a specified period of time and afterwards readout that data and check for bit flips/data corruption.

Is there a Debian package, that could help me out there or do you know another easy approach? I would have thought about setting every bit to one, for example, and check out if they are still on one afterward, but I guess this is a rather slow and inconvenient approach.

Edit: The built-in NAND flash device is the K9F2G08U0B by Samsung

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before you embark on these tests, I suggest you study up as much as possible on  NAND flash and ECC.  For instance, there is no need to *"set every bit to one"* as that is the same as erasing (a page).  Depending on the specific NAND chip used, the manufacturer will specify an ECC capability, which could vary from 1 bit per sector (for older, high-quality chips) to 6 (or more) bits (for cheaper, mass-quanity chips).  An OS will typically always try to correct any detected errors (or use HW to do so), so your plan is flawed.  U-Boot is capable of performing raw reads (and writes).

Comment: Long-term radiation memory test? Will you be actively bombarding the chips with radiation, or send it to space?

Comment: I plan to expose the chip to radiation with a defined dose rate over a defined time frame

Comment: In my understanding after research, the chip is supported by an ECC with an endurance of 1bit/512Bytes (according to datasheet) using the Hamming method, meaning it can correct 1 bit per chunk and detect 2 bit errors per chunk. A more reliable and strong ECC method would be the BCH method. However, since this seems to be done by internal firmware, I don't know if I can at least have a log of all the errors/corrections determined by ECC to read this out and compare it to a chip not exposed to radiation @sawdust

Comment: How much *"research"* was accomplished in the 5 hours between comments? Your *"understanding"* seems vague and poorly worded.  That Samsung NAND has no ECC capability; it must be provided. The Atmel SoC on that SoM has a hardware ECC controller.  BCH algorithm is not *"more reliable and strong"* than Hamming;  it's a matter of correction capability and efficiency (i.e. code length).  Your use of *"internal firmware"* is meaningless jargon;  internal to what?  You still seem unaware that bit errors can occur during normal NAND operations.  Your experiment is flawed.